# CefSharp adding ssl proxy makes app not to load any websites

Tags: wpf, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I cloned example project from https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample and tried to run WPF example. everything works like expected, until I add ProxyOption before Cef.Initialize...

my proxy options are:

```
CefSharpSettings.Proxy = new ProxyOptions("IP", "PORT", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD");
```

I also tried to add CefCommandLineArgs:

```
"proxy-server", "USERNAME:PASSWORD@IP:PORT"
```

and websites does not load...

My question is: HOW CAN I SET HTTP/HTTPS PROXY ON CefSharp?

Comment: Does Chrome work using the same command line arg?

Comment: Haven't tried that, but I don't care about Chrome... I care about CefSharp :)
As for chrome https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/proxy

Comment: Uses the same command line args as Chromium. You should test to confirm the proxy is actually working. Read https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#proxy-resolution

Comment: The relevant chromium doco is https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-settings#TOC-Command-line-options-for-proxy-settings

Comment: @amaitland OK, I have another question. Can you confirm if CefSharp supports https proxy scheme?

Comment: I've never tried, if it works in Chrome then it'll likely work. I don't see Chrome supporting the username and password in the URL. Best check in Chrome

Comment: Confirming that username/password cannot be set using command line args https://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=16582#p41050

Comment: And how could I authorize proxy?

Comment: Read the link I posted already.